# Dock acting strange since last update

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Running 18.04 LTS on a Lenovo E480 laptop. I install all software updates as they show up.

When I mouseover certain programs in favorites (TeXWorks, in particular), the dock bounces up and down.

Also, when I connect to a second screen (I keep my dock at the bottom, only in the main display), the dock sometimes shows up in the middle/top-ish of the main screen. The only fix I found is restarting the laptop.

Comment: I have the same issue. There is an unresolved bug posted on Launchpad about it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1881941